# Changes made in designer not visible

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I have a really stupid problem that I just don't understand : I have a WPF application project, and no matter what I do, the changes I do in the designer are not visible when I run the application ! I have been working on this project for weeks and all over sudden it's not working anymore.

However, when I change something in the code (MainWindow.xaml.cs for instance) it works. I tried showing a messagebox and it showed up when i started the application.

It's probably really silly, but I can't figure this out !

Any ideas what might be causing this ?

**EDIT :**

If I add this code :

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("test");
```

to the MainWindow constructor the MessageBox appears :

[image]

but if I try to just change the color of a button in designer :

[image]

the button doesn't change at runtime :

[image]

Comment: can you paste your code

Comment: I have A LOT of code that really wouldn't help.

Comment: can you reproduce your problem with short demonstration ?

Comment: @Julien put your xaml code

Comment: is your  VS setup correct, ? do you build all your files everytime ? try clean and build, looks like either your project isn't building or vs is not detecting the file changed

Comment: thanks @Muds ! I already tried the rebuild but the clean AND rebuild worked.

Comment: phew,, MSDN Says- Rebuild (devenv.exe)

"Cleans and then builds the specified solution configuration."

Comment: but there is always some magic some where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved from comments --

is your VS setup correct ?
do you build all your files every time ?

try clean and re - build,

looks like either your project isn't building or VS is not detecting the file changed

Answer (score 0):

Had encountered the same issue before. Just closed but save your solution and try re-openning it. I also restarted my computer just to make sure everything is refreshed. :-) For some reason, it helped.